# How to find and fix image breakpoints when designing to a HTML template

Tags: responsive-design, image, templates

When working with a responsive design framework it is easy to specify the breakpoints based on the viewport and resolution that you are designing for.

However, in situations where a generic HTML template is given due to technical constraints, how do people normally figure out what the image breakpoints are and design for it?

An example might be the [Microsoft ADFS sign in page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn280950.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that has a default HTML template which you can customize. But in the case where there is no access to the code or markup then there needs to be some way to make sure that the image doesn't break at different screen resolutions and aspect ratios.

Are there other helpful tips and techniques to deal with this situation?

One useful tool I have found is: http://www.responsivebreakpoints.com/

Answer (score 0):

I set
`width:100%; height:auto; max-width:"the images' horizontal size"`
for quick and dirty image resizing.